# Folding hands in hold 'em poker

Tags: texas-hold-em

Please settle this: Player A calls Player B’s hand. Player B shows the winning hand. Player A just folds his hand without showing it. Does Player B have a right to see Player A’s cards?

Comment: @HerbWolfe I don't think this is a duplicate.  In the dup it is the other player showing.

Comment: asking to see another players hand has the same rules rather or not the player is the winner or loser, caller or bettor. Its covered in the other post.

Comment: @dup   This was not an out of turn reveal.  But I am OK with the close.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, where B is both the last aggressor and the apparent winner of the hand, the only reason for him to want to see A's hand is if he suspects collusion. He can ask the dealer and/or floorman to show A's hand, but the floorman may decline (depending on house policy). It is universally considered rude to make such a request without good reason.

If the floorman does show A's hand, it is live and will win the pot if it is better than B's, so he asks to see it at his own risk (in different situations the dealer will kill a hand before showing it).

Answer (score 0):

If Player A called Player B then Player B was last aggressor.

Last aggressor (Player B) is obligated to show first.

In some rooms Player A is NOT required to show.  In some rooms anyone in the the hand can request a hand be shown.  It would not make sense to have an order to show if all players had to automatically show anyway.

If you have the nuts from any position it is proper etiquette to show immediately.  If you wait your turn that is a form of a slow roll.

[Good example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xou55P5DJE4)

If Player A showed first (out of order) is Player B required to show is more interesting. In most rooms Player B would be required to show. But Player A could have just waited for Player B to show first if s/he wanted to see.

Comment: It's not really slow-roll to wait for your turn to show, however it's polite to say something like "I probably have you beat, please show your hand first".

Comment: @Jonast92 I probably have you beat and show the nuts.  That would go over really good.

Comment: I've done this plenty of times if I really want to see what villain had. I don't do this against donkeys since I don't care what garbage they have but against good regs or pros I want all the information I can get. It's their turn to show, they have to show to claim the pot and provide the information or muck their hand. By telling them that you probably have them beat, regardless of whether you have the coconuts or simply a strong hand, is polite but it's stupid to let them get away with showing their hand if the information will help you in the future.

Comment: If someone gets upset for you not fast-rolling, then consider them a fish and move along.

Comment: @Jonast92 I don't have a question here.